# How to set default value for a field in Azure Logic Apps' trigger JSON Schema?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm setting up an Azure Logic Apps Workflow with a trigger, but am currently unable to define default values for such trigger's fields in the JSON Schema.

I have enabled JSON Schema validation and Required fields as described here: https://www.danrigby.com/2018/08/27/enable-schema-validation-and-required-fields-in-logicapps/

My JSON Schema currently looks as follows:

```
{
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "required": [
                "delay"
            ]
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "startTime"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "callbackUrl": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "delay": {
            "default": 0,
            "minimum": 0,
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "startTime": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "callbackUrl"
    ],
    "type": "object"
}
```

I've also tried replacing `default` with `defaultValue` but without luck.

I expected `delay` to be populated as 0 when absent, instead it is interpreted as `null` within Azure Logic Apps Workflow, causing the failure of following boolean conditions such as `delay is greater than 0` because they don't expect null values to get evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the JSON Schema is just used for validation here, as it is in many scenarios. The `default` property is ignored by many implementations as mentioned in the [official docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html).

Instead, you can use this expression where you need the default value on `null`

```
if (equals(triggerBody()?['delay'], null), triggerBody()?['delay'], 0)
```